# Query to retrieve list of privileges in different database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, mariadb

Is there a query (not a stored procedure or a command) which can be executed to retrieve list of privileges for objects (Tables, Views, Stored Procedures, Functions & Triggers) and users for a particular database (require following columns -- Schema name, Object type, Object name, Permission)?

1. MySQL --
   Tried this but require a consolidate query -- SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
2. Oracle --
   Tried this SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS but it provides for tables and views only
3. MariaDB --
4. SQL --

Answer (score 1):

As of **Oracle** (I don't know other databases; by the way, I believe you wrongly used the `sql` tag. It is the *language*, while the database you're probably talking about is named the MS SQL Server), remember that you can *ask the Dictionary*. For example:

```
SQL> select * From dictionary where lower(comments) like '%grant%';

TABLE_NAME           COMMENTS
-------------------- -------------------------------------------------------
<snip>
USER_ROLE_PRIVS      Roles granted to current user
USER_SYS_PRIVS       System privileges granted to current user
USER_TAB_PRIVS       Grants on objects for which the user is the owner, gran
                     tor or grantee

USER_TAB_PRIVS_MADE  All grants on objects owned by the user
USER_TAB_PRIVS_RECD  Grants on objects for which the user is the grantee
<snip>
20 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

Saying that `DBA_TAB_PRIVS` (which displays info for the whole database; I'm running this from an ordinary user, not a DBA) shows only tables and views, well - you are **wrong**. It displays procedures as well. How do I know?

This is my procedure and I'll grant `execute` privilege to `mike`:

```
SQL> select object_name, object_type from user_procedures where object_name = 'P_TEST';

OBJECT_NAME     OBJECT_TYPE
--------------- -------------------
P_TEST          PROCEDURE

SQL> grant execute on p_test to mike;

Grant succeeded.
```

What do I see?

```
SQL> select grantee, owner, table_name, privilege
  2  from user_tab_privs
  3  where table_name = 'P_TEST';

GRANTEE    OWNER      TABLE_NAME           PRIVILEGE
---------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
MIKE       SCOTT      P_TEST               EXECUTE

SQL>
```

Here it is. So yes, you were wrong.